# How can I change boolean value saved in MySQL table by a button with ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have an Angular app which will return some values and one of them is boolean.

I have added a button in the table which i want give the function of making the boolean false in MySQL.

How can I do that?

My table -

```
` <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th ng-repeat="heading in data1.headings">{{heading}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="reservation in reservations">
                            <td>{{reservation.user_id}}</td> 
                            <td>{{reservation.day}}/{{reservation.month}}/{{reservation.year}}</td>
                            <td>{{reservation.from}} To {{reservation.to}}</td>
                            <td><button ng-click="disapprove()">Disapprove</button></td>


                        </tr>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>`
```

my controller -

```
.controller('TablesTripsController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        'use strict';
        $scope.trips = [];
        $http.get('/api/index.php/trips').success(function(response) {

            $scope.trips= response.trips;
        });
        $scope.data = {
            headings: ['Id', 'From', 'To', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Reg No.', 'Contact', 'Driver Name','Pick Up', 'Drop Off']
        };
        $scope.selTrip= function(trip){
            $scope.reservations = [];
            $scope.user=[];
            $http.get('/api/index.php/trips/'+trip.id+'/reservations').success(function(response) {

            $scope.reservations= response.reservations;
            $scope.user= response.reservations.user;
        });
            $scope.disapprove = function(){


            }
        }   
        $scope.data1 = {
            headings: ['User ID', 'Date', 'Route', 'Time','Disapprove?']
        };
    }]);
```

How can I write the disapprove function here to make it false from true?

The response are in Json format. and the field of the boolean I am talking about is `is_approved`.

Answer (score 0):

you need somethink in your server side to query mysql.

angular can make an Ajax request to a web service (php/java) on your server, and this web service should query Mysql to change the value of the boolean

some example :
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp